# Spring integration routing to subflow in different class

Tags: java, spring-integration

I am struggling for a couple of days to make this work. What I am trying to accomplish is to call different subflows (that are Integration flow), from the main flow, based on message content and after subflow finishes to return to main flow. Its like delegation responsibility to a specific class to finish something and to return to main flow. That responsibility can also require some steps, so its implemented as flow as well. Here is my main flow:

```
public IntegrationFlow processingFlow(
  MessageChannel eventIn,
  MessageChannel eventOut,
  ChangedEventsLoader changedEventsLoader,
  CalculatorRouter calculatorRouter) {

return IntegrationFlows.from(eventIn)
    .handle(changedEventsLoader)
    .route(
        CalculatorRouter::getSportId,
        CalculatorRouter::routeCalculation)
    .channel(eventOut)
    .get();
```

}

Here is implementation of router:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CalculatorRouter {
  private final MessageChannel eventOut;

  public RouterSpec<Integer, MethodInvokingRouter> routeCalculation(
      RouterSpec<Integer, MethodInvokingRouter> mapping) {
    return mapping
        .channelMapping(1, "subflowCalculationChannel")
        .defaultOutputToParentFlow();
  }

  public Integer getSportId(Event event) {
    return 1;
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel subflowCalculationChannel() {
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
  }
}
```

and here is an example of one subflow:

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CalculatorExample {

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow calculateProbabilities(MessageChannel subflowCalculationChannel) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(subflowCalculationChannel)
        .<Event>handle((p, m) -> p * 2)
        .get();
  }
}
```

The trouble is that subflow miss some connection with main flow. I tried to solve that by using defaultOutputToParentFlow() in routing part but that's not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting some version we made a decision to align the Java DSL router behavior with the standard configuration with annotations or XML. So, if we send to the router, we can't expect reply from there. We can continue only with the channel as an output from sub-flows.

In your case you have a `.channel(eventOut)` in the main flow. So, all your routing sub-flows should reply exactly to this channel:

```
    .<Event>handle((p, m) -> corners1H2HCustomBet.getCalculation(p))
    .channel(eventOut)
    .get();
```

I think `.defaultOutputToParentFlow();` just does not make anything for you because you don't have a default mapping. And it is already slightly different story: it does not have any effects for other mappings.

Also pay attention to this JavaDoc:

```
/**
 * Add a subflow as an alternative to a {@link #channelMapping(Object, String)}.
 * {@link #prefix(String)} and {@link #suffix(String)} cannot be used when subflow
 * mappings are used.
 * <p> If subflow should refer to the external {@link IntegrationFlow} bean and
 * there is a requirement to expect reply from there, such a reference should be
 * wrapped with a {@code .gateway()}:
 * <pre class="code">
 * {@code
 *     .subFlowMapping(false, sf -> sf.gateway(evenFlow())))
 * }
 * </pre>
 * @param key the key.
 * @param subFlow the subFlow.
 * @return the router spec.
 */
public RouterSpec<K, R> subFlowMapping(K key, IntegrationFlow subFlow) {
```

Not related to your channel-based routing configuration, but may be useful in the future.

**UPDATE**

Here is a sample (Kotlin) for `subFlowMapping` and return to the main flow:

```
    @Bean
    fun splitRouteAggregate() =
            IntegrationFlow { f ->
                f.split()
                        .route<Int, Boolean>({ o -> o % 2 == 0 },
                                { m ->
                                    m.subFlowMapping(true) { sf -> sf.gateway(oddFlow()) }
                                            .subFlowMapping(false) { sf -> sf.gateway(evenFlow()) }
                                })
                        .aggregate()
            }

    @Bean
    fun oddFlow() =
            IntegrationFlow { flow ->
                flow.handle<Any> { _, _ -> "odd" }
            }

    @Bean
    fun evenFlow() =
            IntegrationFlow { flow ->
                flow.handle<Any> { _, _ -> "even" }
            }
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I hoped that there is some way to specify output channel outside of sub-flows.

Comment: Well, you can add it into the `replyChannel` header using an `enrichHeaders()` before the `route()` in the main flow.

Comment: do you have example using subFlowMapping with Integration flow. That looks event better, since I don't need to specify channels

Comment: I've just added a Kotlin sample about sub-flows and gateways.

Comment: thank you a lot. I will try to make it work for my case.

Comment: I switched routeCalculation (RouterSpec) to use subFlowMapping, and that is working fine for cases which I specified in subFlowMapping. For cases not covered in subFlowMapping I tried to use defaultSubFlowMapping but somehow that is not working. Any suggestion?

Comment: The message is not processed further, and I am getting error: Retries exhausted for message....Execution of Rabbit message listener failed. I can post updated code if it's necessary. I know it's not working because I am getting expected logs for cases specified in subFlowMapping and for all other cases (that should be hopefully covered by defaultSubFlowMapping) I am getting error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181344/discussion-between-dragutin-vujovic-and-artem-bilan).